# How to increase the timeout of http requests in angular 6?

Tags: angular, http, timeout, angular6

Im using http post to send some datas in to database. For 3000 records it is posting fine & I can display the success popup message. But for 11,000 & more than records posting takes some time. Posting is happening fine in backend. But in the front end, Im not able to get proper response, My console error message is given below:

```
 HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: null, ok: false, …}

 message: "Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error"
```

name: "HttpErrorResponse"

Could anyone please help me with this. Trying to solve this from last 2 days.

My ts file:

```
 this.importP(importForm)
      .subscribe(r => {
         console.log("response : ", r);
        this.$modal.successModal({
          title: 'Import P',
          msg: 'File Uploaded Successfully!'
        });

      })
```

My service file:

```
      public importP(data): Observable<any> {
         const headers = new HttpHeaders();
         headers.set('content-type', null);
         headers.set('Accept', 'multipart/form-data');
         let b = this.http.post(APIConstants.IMPORTPREFERENCE, data, { headers 
       });
    return b;
    }
```

Comment: This could be any number of things; I don't think it's related to a timeout. Even so, XHR requests timeouts are infinite by default and usually controlled by the browser (Chrome is 1 min). Exactly how much data are you uploading? What server setup are you using? Can you find a breakpoint in request size where this breaks? It could be that your server is set to only allow a certain amount of memory per ajax request handler, or something similar.

Comment: @joh04667 Im using node server. my data upload takes some 4 to 5 mins.

Comment: Did you find a solution ?